# using retain to keep track of maximum value

Tags: macros, sas

I have a macro `CVI` that return a `y` for a given `x`. To simpliy it, assume

```
%macro CVI(Nt);
  %local result;
  %let result = %sysevalf(2*&Nt**2-&Nt);
  &Result;
%mend;
```

This works as expected

```
%macro run;
data _null_;
  %do i = 1 %to 5;
    %let s = %CVI(&i); 
    %put &i &s;
  %end;
run;
%mend;
```

But I tried to find the maximum in a given interval, say between `9` and `25`.

I modified `%run` a bit but no luck.

```
%macro run2;
  data _null_;
    retain max;
    %do i = 9 %to 25;
      %if max < %CVI(&i) %then max = %CVI(&i);
      %else max = max;
    %end;
  run;
%mend;
```

Did I miss anything inside macro?

Comment: Not an answer, but I think this may be better accomplished via proc rcmp rather than a macro

Comment: @Reeza `proc fcmp`? I will look into it.

Comment: Oops, yes, proc FCMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
%macro run2;
  data a;
  drop x;
    max = %CVI(9);    
    %do i = 9 %to 25;
       x = %CVI(&i);
      if max < x then max = x;      
    %end;
  run;
%mend;
```

also you should change the name of your macro %run to something else. run is a reserved word .

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to generate? If so, then start creating a macro from here.

```
data _null_;
  do i = 9 to 25;
    if max < 2*i**2-i then max = 2*i**2-i;
  end;
    Put MAX=;
run;
```